# Multiple classes, onCreate saved instance issue

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, wakelock

Ok, so quick explanation. I have an app that consists of 3 files.

Main.java, License.java ,App.java

For an example. This app does function 100% except for what i am about to ask. This app does contain a webview and in here lays the issue. I have researched and most everything points to orientation changes. I am not having a problem with orientation because i force landscape at the moment. I am having an issue with the phone going to sleep.

When it wakes, it reloads the page inside the webview. I can add a lock for that, but if someone manually locks their phone, then unlocks it, it will be the same response. Or can you manually lock it if the force wake is in the app? Guess i need to test that one.

Anyways, i am guessing the saveinstancestate will remember the location in the webview and reload to it? If so, which of the oncreates does it go in?

Main is launched when it first opens, this one calls the license, if it passes it then opens the application

Answer (score 0):

Do you do anything special on onPause and onResume? When the phone goes to sleep, as far as I know only onPause should be called, and when woken up onResume. Maybe you load the webview content in onResume?

Also, if you want to share some data amongst your activities, you could try using an Application context instead. I.e. in the AndroidManifest file define a class to be used as application (just like you do with activities, with the "android:name" attribute). The class of course should be a sub-class of "android.app.Application".

See also:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: No, i do not do anything in the onPause nor onResume. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Just to follow up, i added savedinstance, onsave, onreload, etc.. and none of it really worked. So i ended up using the webview to store the last POST var sent and when it reloads, it uses that to restore the page.